# How do I use the width limit and use gap at the same time?

Tags: css, flexbox

I have a problem, I need a form that will be limited in width and use the gap.

[CodePen](https://codepen.io/reeeeem/pen/wvxGGBe)

```css
body {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

.container {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;

    gap: 18px;

    min-height: 100vh;
}

.container--example {
    background-color: #000;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
    <div class="container--example"></div>
    <div class="container--example"></div>
    <div class="container--example"></div>
    <div class="container--example"></div>
</div>
```

Here the div is stretched to 100%, the whole screen, I can set the width settings on the element in the container, but then gap will not work.
Thank you so much in advance for your answer

Unfortunately, I do not know how to fix this problem, I hope to find the answer here.

UPD: Also, it is possible to put widths on the text and so on, but it's too much of a pain.

Comment: You have one div that you apply flex to you need at least 1 more element to use gap.

Comment: Yes, I know, I only showed one div to explain. But thank you, changed the question so that there were no such questions.

Comment: Well then your example does not make sense at all. Make a better one, please.

Comment: See now your gap works fine.

Comment: Of course, I had no problem with the gap, but how can I reduce the width of the content while leaving it centered and with a working gap at the same time?

Comment: `width: 50%` on `.container--example`

Comment: Yeah, I was thinking about that option too, but I don't really like that there's a restriction on every element inside, no other way?

Comment: https://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/w/width/ pick option that you like.

Comment: Wow, thank you, incredible!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set a padding to the parent of `.container`, in the example that would be `body`.

CSS `body { padding: 0 2rem }` would create a space of `2rem` on either side of `.container`, which would be true for every child of `body`.

With a little math you can even make that space responsive:

- 16px space on a 320px viewport
- 256px space on a 1920px viewport

would yield equation **y = 0.15x + 32** using Linear Equation **y=mx+b** for points **p1(320,16)** and **p2(1920,256)**.

```css
body {
    margin: 0;
    /* Using y=mx+b => y = 0.15x + 32 for points p1(320,16) and p2(1920,256) */
    padding: 0 calc(15vw - 2rem);
}

.container {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;

    gap: 18px;

    max-width: ;
    min-height: 100vh;
}

.container--example {
    background-color: #000;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
    <div class="container--example"></div>
    <div class="container--example"></div>
</div>
```